# How to implement bulk editing of columns in MUI X Datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I noticed that the mUI v6 documentation adds a batch column edit function：
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/cell-selection/#controlled-cell-selection

but is there a way to do this in the `Datagrid` instead of the `DataGridPremium`